# Optional input for average calculation

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, indexing

I am currently coding a very simple python script and i am quite new to python, and my question is:

how can I do that so if the user doesn't write anything as input, that it doesn't implement the variable in the calculation?

Here the code:

```
def Calc():
    elif whatDo == "2":

        EPS = int(input("EPS: "))
        SciencePC = int(input("SciencePC: "))
        ScienceSVT = int(input("ScienceSVT: "))
        PhysiqueChimie = int(input("PhysiqueChimie: "))
        Francais = int(input("Francais: "))
        Allemand = int(input("Allemand: "))
        Anglais = int(input("Anglais: "))
        AnglaisLitt = int(input("AnglaisLitt: "))
        HistoireGéographie = int(input("HistoireGéographie: "))
        EMC = int(input("EMC: "))
        Mathématiques = int(input("Mathématiques: "))


        matières = [EPS, SciencePC, ScienceSVT, PhysiqueChimie, Francais, Allemand, Anglais, AnglaisLitt, HistoireGéographie, EMC, Mathématiques]

        sumOf = sum(matières)

        print(sumOf)

        average = sumOf/11 #This number (11) would then be changed to a variable

        print("\nTa moyenne est de: " + str(average))

        save = input("\nVeut tu sauvegarder cette moyenne comme ta nouvelle moyenne? (y/*): ")

        if save == "y":
            print("\nsaving value: " + str(average) + " as new value...")
            file2write = open("currentValue", 'w')
            file2write.write(str(average))
            file2write.close()
            print("succesfully saved!")
            Calc()
```

BTW : There is some text in french as you certainly noticed

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  What you've posted does not run as given, and most of your code does not apply to the question you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keeping everything in lists, you can use a loop and try block to skip empty input.

```
   elif whatDo == "2":

        matières_strings = ["EPS", "SciencePC", "ScienceSVT", "PhysiqueChimie", "Francais", "Allemand", "Anglais", "AnglaisLitt", "HistoireGéographie", "EMC", "Mathématiques"]

        matières = []
        for s in matières_strings:
            input_string = input("{}: ".format(s))
            
            try:
                val = int(input_string) ## if the user inputs nothing, casting to int will fail
                                        ## and will exit the try block, thus no value will be appended to the list
                matières.append(val)
            except ValueError:
                pass
                
        sumOf = sum(matières)

        print(sumOf)

        average = sumOf/len(matières) 

        print("\nTa moyenne est de: " + str(average))

        save = input("\nVeut tu sauvegarder cette moyenne comme ta nouvelle moyenne? (y/*): ")

        if save == "y":
            print("\nsaving value: " + str(average) + " as new value...")
            file2write = open("currentValue", 'w')
            file2write.write(str(average))
            file2write.close()
            print("succesfully saved!")
            Calc()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different variable as my divisor. Then you could count the number of inputs that aren't '0' using a list comprehension and assign it to that variable.

```
matières = [EPS, SciencePC, ScienceSVT, PhysiqueChimie, Francais, Allemand, Anglais, AnglaisLitt, HistoireGéographie, EMC, Mathématiques]

sumOf = sum(matières)

print(sumOf)

nonZero = [i for i in matières if i != 0]
numberOf = len(nonZero)

average = sumOf/numberOf
```

Comment: Alright, but isn't there a way so that if i give no input, that the script still goes on? because at the moment if i doesn't type anything it just crashes and stops

Comment: Amelia Brown just posted a more complete answer that answers your questions.